# Find the signs of elements in a list such that their sum is equal to zero

Tags: optimization, summation, discrete-optimization

I have a set $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots x_N\} \in [0;1]^N$ containing $N$ elements, initially all positive. My goal is to find a vector of signs $S = \{s_1, s_2, \dots s_N\} \in \{-1; 1\}^N$ such that:

$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N} x_i s_i = 0$$

In other words, I want to be able to find the signs to associate to the various $x_i$ such that their sum is null.
Do you know if there is a standard way to do that? Or to obtain the closest sum to $0$?

Thanks in advance!

Bastien

---

### Precisions

I know for sure that the solution exists, or is very close to $0$ (in case of precision loss in previous computations).

I have already investigated the following ideas:

- Exhaustive search guided by a heuristic function (works up to $|X| \approx 30$).
- Simple genetic algorithm (works up to $|X| \approx 40$).
- Suggestion by Math1000: dynamic programming (I don't think it will work due to the exponential number of sums, but I may be wrong).

Comment: Note that if x_1=1, and all the others x_n=0, then there is no such vector S.

Comment: I forgot to precise that I know for sure that the solution exists. Sorry about that, I will edit the main post

Comment: This sounds similar to the subset sum problem. Try a dynamic programming approach, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I investigated it a bit, but I think it won't work. For every pair of elements, you have 4 possible sums (++, +-, -+, --). Therefore, since we combine 2 elements at every iteration, we have twice the same number of elements to sum at each step.